# How to search access database and display in Listview VB6?

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I'm creating a program where the user can search items in an access database and results are displayed in a listview.

When I click search all items are displayed but when I enter an item in the textbox then search nothing is displayed.

This is my code

```
Private Sub cmdProdSearch_Click()
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim list_item As ListItem
Dim itm As ListItem

db_file = db_file & "ProductsDatabase.mdb"
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = _
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=F:\VB and     Database\ProductsDatabase.mdb;Persist Security Info=False" & _
"Data Source=" & db_file & ";" & _
"Persist Security Info=False"
conn.Open
Set rs = conn.Execute("Select * from Export")

ListView1.ListItems.Clear

If InStr(1, rs!Product, txtProduct.Text, vbTextCompare) Then
With ListView1
.View = lvwReport
.FullRowSelect = True
Do While Not rs.EOF
Set itm = .FindItem(txtProduct.Text, lvwText, , lvwPartial)
Set list_item = .ListItems.Add(, , rs!Product)
list_item.SubItems(1) = rs!barcode & ""
list_item.SubItems(2) = rs!quantity & ""
list_item.SubItems(3) = rs!Department
rs.MoveNext
Loop
End With
End If
End Sub
```

Any ideas what is wrong?
I dont get an errors just nothing displays.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the if condition and the loop in the wrong way. Your if condition check whether the current record's product field is same as the entered text. If so, loop through the records and add it to the listview.

You could do the searching in two ways:

One is to use LIKE in the sql. For example, `SELECT * FROM Export WHERE product LIKE 'a%'` would return the records with product field starting with "a".
For more details: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Anther way is to loop through all the records one by one and using an if condition(like you have now), check whether the field contains the search text. If you are using this, then the change you have to make on your present code is, move the if condition inside the loop. So, it would be like inside the while loop, you will check for the match using the if condition.

Comment: Thank you. I just got rid of the If Statement altogether and changed the query similar to the one you suggested. Seems to be working now. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Please accept this as answer(by clicking on the Tick Mark, near my post). This means, you have selected my post as the solution. Good luck :)